# Systemd stuck at "reached multi-user.target"

Tags: systemd, udev

After install systemd and change the default target to mutli-user.target(since i don't install X server), the boot stuck at 
`[OK] reached target Multi-User System`

I also find the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.wants` is empty, so i add a basic.target link to `/lib/systemd/system/basic.target`.

Now it show a getty login prompt, but **no keyboard response**, I can't figure out where is the problem. A wrong systemd config? or miss some driver? I even don't know how to get some useful log>_<. A good news is I didn't see any service fail when the PC boot, everything is [OK], so i guess the problem is in systemd.

Comment: Have you tried switching TTYs?

Comment: yes, but no response :-(